# Where to put the external JAR files?

Tags: java

I am working with the Eclipse IDE and I know how to use an external JAR. I know how to add them in to build path. I am getting the perfect output in eclipse but when I navigate to the bin folder of eclipse where `.class` file is located in the command prompt, when I use the command

```
java MySQLConnector
```

It is returning an error as class not found. I think the code is not able to find `MySQLConnector.jar` file. How do I add the JAR file while executing the class.

I have already generated the class file, I used `javac` and got no errors while compilation. Please tell me how should I proceed further?

My class name is Main, my mysqlconnector.jar file is in C drive. I am using the following command:

```
javac -cp c:/mysqlconnector.jar Main.java
java -cp c:/mysqlconnector.jar Main
```

I am getting no compilation error. But getting error after executing the class file as:
Error: Could not find or load main class Main.

Comment: do you want everything to be complied into a single jar'

Comment: May be. May not be.. I don't have any intention of making JAR file but I will give a try

Comment: i mean do you want the external mysql jar to be embedded with your main jar file.....like that do you want as a single executable jar file

Comment: not embedding with the external jar...embedding external jar within the main jar

Comment: you need to reference _all_ of the jars you want to use `-cp project.jar;c:/mysqlconnector.jar;...`.

Answer (score 2):

Build path is different from runtime classpath. Make sure jar is available in runtime classpath to avoid above error. You may use `java -cp` flag to set classpath

Example:

```
java -cp locationToJar yourProgram
```

Comment: Does LocationToJar means complete path?

Comment: @Dibya: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Getting error as `Error: Could not find or load main class Main`.@Nambari

Comment: You are planning to run MYSQLConnector right? It seems there is no .class file with main method is available in classpath.

Comment: Can you update your question with exact command you are trying? As well as which class you want to run also?

Comment: I am using this command. My present directory contains the .class file `java -cp c:/mysqlconnector.jar Main`

Answer (score 0):

Use `-cp` and specify the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Make the classpath reference to these jars in the lib folder.

If you are using any external jars, then you can use something like below.

You can always create a lib folder and use within your project.  This way, it will always part of your project. You can't need to search for these jars outside (unless there is a common pool of jars that are being used by your org).

Answer (score 0):

As Nambari stated, build path is different than the path used during runtime. Also, for Eclipse may be different too if you are using an external method/tool to compile your project.
First of all, you need to identify the runtime context and then setup the classpath accordingly.
Some suggestions:
- Put your *.jar where your final projects is going to need it.
- Setup the build path for Eclipse pointing to that location to reference your jars.